# How To Multiply / Divide Entry Box With A Number, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Hey im pretty new to python and im taking a class in high school. For an assignment im working on we have to make a tkinter gui that includes the widgets, label, buttons, entry box, radio or check buttons, frames, and a display box. I am making a kilometers to miles converter that can do the opposite if chosen, there will be radio buttons that the user can choose to choose which one they would like to calculate, but i am having a lot of trouble on the calculation part because i cant get the entry box number to multiple or divide by 1.609 or any number.
Heres the code i have now, I apologize for the mess and how bad it probably

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

# Customize main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI Assignment')



# Create the frames, right, left, and bottom, and pack them
bframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, padx=100, pady=50)
bframe.pack(side='bottom')
rframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, padx=100, pady=50)
rframe.pack(side='right')
lframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, padx=100, pady=50)
lframe.pack(side='left')


# Make the label and the entry box for the right frame
dlabel = tk.Label(rframe, text = 'Enter the distance', )
dentry = tk.Entry(rframe, width=75)
# Pack the label and entry
dlabel.pack(side='left')
dentry.pack(side="right")
dist = 3.0
temp =(dentry.get())
# Create the convert command
def convert():
    if radio_var.get()==1:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Distance',temp / dist )

# Make the convert and quit buttons
b = tk.Button(bframe, text="Convert", command=convert)
quit = tk.Button(bframe, text='Quit', command=root.destroy)

# Pack the buttons
b.pack(side='left')
quit.pack(side='right')

# Make the radio variable 
radio_var = tk.IntVar()
radio_var.set(1)

# Make the radio buttons for the left frame
rb = tk.Radiobutton(lframe, text='Km to Miles', variable=radio_var, value=1)
rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(lframe, text='Miles to Km', variable=radio_var, value=2)

# Pack The Radio Buttons
rb.pack()
rb2.pack()

    

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having here is that you're trying to divide `temp`, a string, by `dist`, a float. You need to convert `temp` to a float before converting it using `float(temp)`. Also, since you set `temp` once during your script, it will only ever refer to the value that was in the input box as soon as the variable was assigned. In order to fix this, you have to call `dentry.get()` inside of your `convert()` function rather than outside of it.